# Embedding plot into template and serving from bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to combine the two bokeh examples [embed_multiple.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_multiple.py) and [simple_stream.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/server/simple_stream.py) to have dynamic graphs served within a template from bokeh-server.

The aim is to have dynamic graphs embedded in a layout with additional information such as text and links.

The below code will produce the HTML file as expected from embed_multiple.py, but the bokeh_server window only displays the plots (no header / body info is preserved).

```
    import time
    import numpy as np

    from bokeh.plotting import cursession, figure, show, output_server
    from bokeh.models import GlyphRenderer, Range1d
    from bokeh.embed import components
    from jinja2 import Template

    # static pages requirements
    import webbrowser
    import os
    import six

    output_server("simple_stream")

    # live graph example data
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 200)
    y = np.sin(x)
    # create some data
    x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    y1 = [0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 25, 28, 4, 7]
    x2 = [2, 5, 7, 15, 18, 19, 25, 28, 9, 10, 4]
    y2 = [2, 4, 6, 9, 15, 18, 0, 8, 2, 25, 28]
    x3 = [0, 1, 0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 8, 9]
    y3 = [0, 8, 4, 6, 9, 15, 18, 19, 19, 25, 28]

    # select the tools we want
    TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

    # live graph example figure
    p = figure(title="Simple streaming example")
    p.line(x,y, color="Orange", line_width=2)

    # the red and blue graphs will share this data range
    xr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)
    yr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)

    # only the green will use this data range
    xr2 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)
    yr2 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)

    # build our figures
    p1 = figure(x_range=xr1, y_range=yr1, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p1.scatter(x1, y1, size=12, color="red", alpha=0.5)

    p2 = figure(x_range=xr1, y_range=yr1, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p2.scatter(x2, y2, size=12, color="blue", alpha=0.5)

    p3 = figure(x_range=xr2, y_range=yr2, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p3.scatter(x3, y3, size=12, color="green", alpha=0.5)

    # plots can be a single PlotObject, a list/tuple, or even a dictionary
    plots = {'Orange': p, 'Red': p1, 'Blue': p2, 'Green': p3}

    script, div = components(plots)

    template = Template('''<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>
            <h1> embedding multiple graphs - can we do it live?</h1>
            <b> So, this text will show up on the static page, but not from Bokeh server! <br \> I must be missing something... </b>
            <style> div{float: left;} </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
            {{ script }}
        </head>
        <body>
        {% for key in div.keys() %}
            {{ div[key] }}
        {% endfor %}
        </body>
    </html>
    ''')

    show(template.render(script=script, div=div))

    html_file = 'embed_multiple.html'
    with open(html_file, 'w') as textfile:
        textfile.write(template.render(script=script, div=div))
    url = 'file:{}'.format(six.moves.urllib.request.pathname2url(os.path.abspath(html_file)))
    webbrowser.open(url)

    ds = p.select({"type": GlyphRenderer})[0].data_source
    while True:
        oldx = ds.data["x"]
        newx = np.hstack([oldx, [oldx[-1] + 4*np.pi/200]])
        ds.data["x"] = newx
        ds.data["y"] = np.sin(newx)
        cursession().store_objects(ds)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

My suspicion is that I am using 'show' incorrectly:

```
    show(template.render(script=script, div=div))
```

Thanks for your time!

Edit:

Using the separate http.server alongside bokeh_server approach outlined in the embed examples (modified [animated.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/animated.py)) still seems to strip HTML! (h1 in [this example](http://codepaste.net/ia8pp9))

Comment: Quickly looking over the [docs for show](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html), it looks like you're not using `show()` correctly. It seems to be reserved only for `bokeh.plotting.figure` objects, not to send html to the browser, which is what it looks like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a little shaky with what you're trying to do exactly, but I think one concept you're not doing right is showing multiple plots (p - p3) in the right way.

[This](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html#laying-out-multiple-plots) seems to be a nice tutorial on how to format your multi-plot layouts with `bokeh`. I haven't looked at their API until tonight but it seems pretty intuitive.

If you're having issues with something else in the code, maybe edit your question to better reflect that issue and I'll take another stab at it.

Comment: Thanks AusitinA!
I was using the grid layout previously, but want to be able to add other arbitrary things to the layout (text, links etc), which is why I am trying to get the embedded plot approach going...

Comment: After playing around with bokeh these last few nights, I see what you're trying to do and what bokeh is actually doing. The main problem here is the difference between the two examples. embed_multiple.py creates a static html page. Once this page is created, it isn't changed, hence the term static. Now the streaming example is much different. This code makes calls between the front and the backend to manipulate the plot in real-time. Think of the difference between the two examples is the first one takes a picture and the second one takes a video.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this using the method from the embedded example. You'll have to send all data to the browser using the streaming example method. This means static content like the plots and the html. I'm still trying to figure out how your code is working. To me, the html and plots should be in one file and the streaming example show be running in a different window. But, as you note, that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks Austin.
I notice that the streaming code adds its own <head> and <body> wrapper info, so I am digging through the source to see where and how this happens.